# Проблемы с откатом миграции

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

возникли некие проблемы с откатом миграций в базе данных Ruby on Rails.

Прописываю `bundlex exec rake db:reset`

Но в консоли мне пишет, что базу данных использую другие пользователи и сделать reset я не могу.
Как это исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Откат миграции - это `rake db:rollback`. А `reset` - это сброс базы. Использует базу скорее всего ваш запущенный сервер, его надо выключить на время выполнения команды.